# Hamster applet in UNR 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, 9.10, applet

How do I add the hamster applet in Ubuntu netbook remix? 
If I start `/usr/lib/hamster-applet/hamster-applet -w` it works in a window fine.
It is written, I should go on the panel and add, but I guess this is not possible in UNR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible with 9.10 (but not with 10.04), but it's a bit tricky to get to the *Add to panel*-option. Let me cite [Paul Larson](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-netbook-remix-default-settings/+bug/448109/comments/2) from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-netbook-remix-default-settings/+bug/448109):

> This is actually possible to do,
>   although perhaps not as
>   straightforward as many people would
>   like it to be. I was able to just do
>   this on a UNR install by following
>   these steps:
>
> 1. right click on the indicator applet (the icon that looks like an envelope)
> 2. deselect "Lock to panel"
> 3. right-click on it again and select 'Move'
> 4. move it over a bit to the left, thus leaving an open blank area to the
>      right of it
> 5. right click in the blank area and select 'add to panel'
>
> I'd like to make this a wishlist item
>   for now, but it could perhaps be
>   converted to a question as well if it
>   is decided not to pursue this as
>   something that could be improved